# Ball collision to induce Game Over in JS Game

Tags: javascript, function, canvas

I'm trying to brush up my Javascript and making a simple game to get practice. Basically it involves a player ball aspect, and then several rings (all animated on canvas) that bounce in random directions, and game over is resulted when the player ball (controlled by arrow keys) collides with one of the obstacles.
I have the player ball and all obstacles working fine, but the collision is stumping me a little. I've looked through a lot of other examples but none seem to be going about the same thing. Perhaps someone could take a look and offer some advice, here's what I've  been trying:

```
let canvas; 
let brush; 
let obstacles;
let player;

let myKeys = {
    // tracking the arrow keys
    up: false,
    down: false,
    left: false,
    right: false
};

// add a key press event listener to the body
let bodyElem = document.getElementById("body");
bodyElem.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
    if(event.key === "ArrowUp"){
        myKeys.up = true;
    }

    if(event.key === "ArrowDown"){
        myKeys.down = true;
    }

    if(event.key === "ArrowLeft"){
        myKeys.left = true;
    }

    if(event.key === "ArrowRight"){
        myKeys.right = true;
    }
}
);

function Setup(){
    canvas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas");
    brush = canvas.getContext("2d");
}
Setup();
function Clear(){
    brush.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function ToRadians(degrees){
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}

function GetRandomInteger(a, b){ // returns random integer between 2 numbers, //swaps them if first is higher than 2nd
    if (a > b){
        small = b;
        large = a;
    }
    else{
        small = a;
        large = b;
    }
    
    let x = parseInt(Math.random() * (large - small + 1)) + small
    return x;
}

function GetRandomColor(){
    let red = GetRandomInteger(0,255);
    let green = GetRandomInteger(0, 255);
    let blue = GetRandomInteger(0, 255);
    let color = "rgb(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ")";
    return color;
}

class Circle {
    
    constructor(centerX, centerY, radius, dX, dY){
        this.centerX = centerX;
        this.centerY = centerY;
        this.rad = radius;
        this.color = GetRandomColor();
        this.name = "CIRCLE";

        this.dX = dX //movement in x direction
        this.dY = dY; // movement in y direction
    }

    Move(){
                let newX = this.x + this.dX;
        
                if(newX + this.radius >= canvas.width || newX - this.radius < 0){
                    this.dX = -this.dX;
                }
                else{
                    this.x = newX;
                }
        
                let newY = this.y + this.dY;
        
                if (newY + this.radius >= canvas.height || newY - this.radius < 0){
                    this.dY = -this.dY;
                }
                else{
                    this.y = newY;
                }
            }

    MoveUp(){
        if(this.centerY - this.dY - (this.rad - 1) >= 0){
            this.centerY -= this.dY;
        }
    }

    MoveDown(){
        if(this.centerY + this.dY + (this.rad - 1) < canvas.height){
            this.centerY += this.dY;
        }
    }

    MoveLeft(){
        if(this.centerX - this.dX - (this.rad - 1) >= 0){
            this.centerX -= this.dX;
        }
    }

    MoveRight(){
        if(this.centerX + this.dX + (this.rad - 1) < canvas.height){
            this.centerX += this.dX;
        }
    }

    MoveHorizontal(){
        if(this.centerX + this.rad - 1 >= canvas.width || this.centerX - this.rad + 1 < 0){
            this.dX = -this.dX;
        }
        this.centerX += this.dX;
    }

    MoveVertical(){
        if(this.centerY + this.rad >= canvas.height){
            this.dY = -this.dY;
        }
        if(this.centerY - this.rad + 1 < 0){
            this.dY = -this.dY;
        }
        this.centerY += this.dY;
    }

    Draw(isPlayer = false){
        // draws empty circle if enemy, filled circle if player
        brush.beginPath();
        brush.arc(this.centerX, this.centerY, this.rad, ToRadians(0), ToRadians(360));
        if(!isPlayer){
            // if not player object then draw a hollow circle
            brush.strokeStyle = this.color;
            brush.stroke();
        }
        else{
            brush.fillStyle = this.color;
            brush.fill();
        }
    }
}
let randomX=GetRandomInteger(0,canvas.width);

let halfX= canvas.width/2;
let playerStartY=canvas.height-10;

player = new Circle(halfX,playerStartY,25,halfX,playerStartY);

function CreateObstacles(n){
    //creates obstacles
     obstacles = [];
     for(let i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
        
         let speedX= GetRandomInteger(-10,10);
         let speedY= GetRandomInteger(-10,10);
         let enemy = new Circle(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 25, speedX, speedY);
        
         obstacles.push(enemy);}
     
     }

function CreatePlayer(){
   // initializes player
     player = new Circle(halfX,playerStartY,25,10,10);
     player.Draw(isPlayer=true);

}
CreateObstacles(10);
function DrawAndMoveObstacles(){
   //loop through and draw obstacles
        for(let i = 0; i < obstacles.length; i++){

           obstacles[i].Draw();
            obstacles[i].MoveHorizontal();
            obstacles[i].MoveVertical();
            
} }
// setInterval(DrawAndMoveObstacles,300);
CreatePlayer();



function Distance(x1,y1,x2,y2){
    //distance between two circles
    let dis = Math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2);
    return dis;
}

circle1= new Circle(player.x,player.y,25,player.dX,player.dY);
circle2= new Circle(obstacles.x,obstacles.y,25,
        obstacles.dX,obstacles.dY);

function Overlaps(circle1, circle2){
   //here is where I'm having issues...not sure how to fix

   let distance = Distance(circle1.x,circle1.y,circle2.x,circle2.y);
   if(distance < 50){
         
   }
   return true;
    }
 

console.log(Overlaps(player,obstacles));

function CheckCollission(){
    //loop through and see if things collide
     for(let i = 0; i < obstacles.length; i++){
         if (Overlaps(player,obstacles) == true){
            
         }
     }
}

function DrawGameScreen(){
    //putting everything together
    Clear();
    DrawAndMoveObstacles();
    
    player.Draw(true);
    if(myKeys.up===true){
        player.MoveUp();
        player.Draw(true);
        myKeys.up=false;
        player.Draw(true);
        }
    if(myKeys.down===true){
       player.MoveDown();
       player.Draw(true);
       myKeys.down=false;
    player.Draw(true);
   } if(myKeys.left===true){
       player.MoveLeft();
       player.Draw(true);
       myKeys.left=false;
        player.Draw(true);
   } if(myKeys.right===true){
       player.MoveRight();
       player.Draw(true);
       myKeys.right=false;
       player.Draw(true);
   }
   
}
console.log(Distance(player,obstacles));

setInterval(DrawGameScreen,400); //testing it
```

I've been testing it with a GameScreen function running at setInterval (Gamescreen, 400) that has the functions all in one in order to make the pieces move.

Any and all help appreciated, thanks for your patience with a new learner here

Comment: Shouldn't `if (Overlaps(player,obstacles) = true) { ` be `if (Overlaps(player,obstacles) == true){`

Comment: I've been trying but thus far Overlaps(player,obstacle) when I run it in the console only returns "obstacle is not defined" so I don't know if my CheckCollision would operate as desired anyway...I changed it to == but as of yet still same issue

Comment: This also looks wrong `Overlaps(player,obstacles) ` it should be `Overlaps(player,obstacles[i]) `
And why are you redefining circle1 and circle2 in Overlaps with undefined values for x,y,radius,dx,dy ?

Comment: obstacles[i] was what I first tried, but it still comes up that [i] is not defined...I'd also initially put values for circle1 to be (player.x,,player.y, player.radius, player.dX,player.dY) and the same for circle2 being obstacles[i].x and etx, both tried globally and within the function, not sure what I'm doing wrong it just says undefined or runs true constantly :S

Comment: You need to update your question with all your code, there is so many undefined variables you are using that makes it impossible to help you.
I expect your code gives a bunch of javascript errors in the console

Comment: I'll add the rest of the code, you have a point

Comment: It's reuploaded ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code, first you are referencing circle.x and circle.y in Overlaps

```
let distance = Distance(circle1.x,circle1.y,circle2.x,circle2.y);
```

That should be centerX and centerY as defined in your Circle class

so your Overlaps should be modified to:

```
 function Overlaps(circle1, circle2){
   let distance = 
   Distance(circle1.centerX,circle1.centerY,circle2.centerX,circle2.centerY);
       if(distance < 50){
             console.log(distance); // show distance when collision found
             return true;
           }
           return false;
        }
```

The line

```
console.log(Distance(player,obstacles));
```

gives a Nan error in console, obstacles is an array not a circle, so just remove that line

Next make sure you are checking for collisions in your DrawGameScreen so change

```
 function DrawGameScreen(){
            //putting everything together
            Clear();
            DrawAndMoveObstacles();
```

to

```
function DrawGameScreen(){
       //putting everything together
       Clear();
       DrawAndMoveObstacles();
       CheckCollission();
```

finally the global definition of circle1 and circle2 is never used, so just dele the lines

```
circle1= new Circle(player.x,player.y,25,player.dX,player.dY);
circle2= new Circle(obstacles.x,obstacles.y,25,
        obstacles.dX,obstacles.dY);
```

Comment: Thanks so much !! I updated CheckCollision and was able to fix the issue there too thanks to your help

Comment: @Galaxyxo your welcome, if it worked for you then please accept the answer, thx

Comment: Sure ! ..um...how ? haha